# Can data copy will have data issue, if copy done using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

Will there be data issue if file is getting updated frequently in 30 seconds and at the same time file is being copied.
File type - csvfile

I am copying file from one adl to other adl (platform - Azure Databricks).
Copying file using

```py
dbutils.fs.cp(source,target)
```

I tried to find answer in python as well but didn't get.

If anyone have something to perform this approch, solution to this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: What is your source and Target

Answer (score 0):

> **Can data copy will have data issue**

May be **NO**, because I tried to reproduce your scenario in my system, I created and triggered a pipeline which is updating file in every 1 minute in databricks I am continuously coping file from one ADL to another I didn't get any error, it is coping file while file is getting updated in every 1 minute.

To find if file is busy or not, I tried to fetch some data from file if it returns data then it is available for work and copy file from one ADL to another ADL. if file is busy, it will go to else, and print engaged

```py
path = "abfss://demo@demostoragepratik.dfs.core.windows.net/jsonvalue.csv"
if dbutils.fs.head(path, 25):
    print("Available for work")
    "dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://demo@demostoragepratik.dfs.core.windows.net/SampleCSV10000Rc.csv","abfss://demo@pratikdemostorage.dfs.core.windows.net/SampleCSV10000Rc16.csv")
else:
    print("Engaged")
```

- **Execution**

[image]

[image]